# Modify AWS AMI periodically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, autoscaling, amazon-ami

I'm working on a web application which uses node.js as server and MongoDB as database. Both my server and MongoDB is hosted in a same AWS EC2 instance.

Now I'm working on to initiate AWS Auto Scaling for the instance. So if somehow the instance is down it'll automatically make another new instance up. So I'm taking an image of my EC2 instance and creating an AMI and attaching it with the auto scaling, so that when the auto scaling creates a new instance it boots from the AMI, so the new instance will be automatically configured. And this process works fine.

But now the problem is, as my MongoDB is in same EC2 instance the DB is being modified in every second. But I created the AMI manually earlier, so each time the Auto scaling starts a new instance and adds the AMI there, the AMI don't have the updated DB in it and I lost some data.

I got one solution, to dynamically create the AMI using AWS lamda function periodically, but I have not find a way to attach a dynamically create AMI to attach with the auto scaling automatically.

Moreover it's not feasible to modify the AMI after each DB change, so there is still some chance to lose some data.

So can someone tell me what could be the best solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The normal method is to **separate your compute and data**.

The Amazon EC2 instances in the Auto Scaling group **should process requests** but should not store data locally.

The **MongoDB database should be maintained outside the Auto Scaling group** so that all instances in the Auto Scaling group can access it. Even if you only have one instance in the Auto Scaling group, as you point out it might be replaced by another instance. You can then make backups of the database separate to your *worker* instances.

You might also consider using [Amazon DocumentDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/what-is.html), which is compatible with MongoDB.